# D3 Liquid Fill Gauge Wave Not Updating

Tags: jquery, json, d3.js

The Plnkr link below has the D3 Liquid Fill Gauge which i've been trying to modify and so far it works, i can see the number updating automatically but the wave height remains the same.
Going back to the original code i can see it had a random number generator which was passing through "value" as the text label and wave height but now i've replaced it with jQuery/JSON only the text label is being updated.

Note: When changing the value in the JSON file it causes Plnkr to refresh the page and the wave does indeed update, but when i run it locally and it pulls in new data (via PHP file instead of the JSON file) the text changes but the wave doesn't.

Original Gauge: https://gist.github.com/tissera/3f0b647d4928d2960a53738ef683b0a6

Plnkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/OO0fWVlBcXvlpTlZ2FYp/

Answer (score 0):

just had a quick look;

if you take a look at the svg in the DOM you will see that it adds each time a new group . Since the old group is already rendered  you do not see refill animation;

just slightly updated your interval function

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('dummydata.json', function(data) {
    //data = JSON.parse(data);
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        readycount = d.value;
        busycount = d.value2;
        agentcount = d.total;
        })
// clear the old content in svg container  *** Note just quick and dirty solution ***
d3.select("#fillgauge4").selectAll("*").remove();
console.log(readycount);
var config3 = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();
                 config3.textVertPosition = 0.5
                 config3.waveAnimateTime = 1000;
config3.valueCountUp = true;
                 config3.displayPercent = false;
                 config3.waveCount = 1;
                 config3.valueCountUp = true;
var gauge4 = loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge4", readycount, config3);

    })
        },3000);
```

Comment: Ah i had already tried .exit().remove() but didn't try .remove() on its own, but unfortunately this is redrawing the wave from the bottom each time instead of moving up/down depending on the value (as the original example does).
Do i need to place the .remove() in a different position like function GaugeUpdater() inside liquidfill3.js?